# why do you have to add the [I]?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

so I am currently learning javascript on Codecademy. And a weird kind of thing got introduced that I don't quite get.

if you look at the code. you see at the end in console that after logging animals it is a [i] like why is that there? I get that is has something to do with the for loop. But I don't quite understand like why or what that it does. I don't know if question is clear enough but if you just try to explain why it is there and what it does there. that would be greatly appreciated:)

```
const animals = ['Grizzly Bear', 'Sloth', 'Sea Lion'];
for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++){
  console.log(animals[i]);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: `animals` is a variable, in your case an array of stuff.
`animals[i]` is an item in your array, starting from 0. So `animals[0]` is Grizzly Bear, `animals[1]` is a Sloth etc.
Since `i` goes from 0 to the last number of `animals`, you will read and log every field in your array.

Comment: This is a very basic question. you need to go through the programming basics for loops. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Answer (score 0):

the bracket notation is used to specify the index of the array you are looping through. You can always read more about javascript arrays on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)